# Adding items to shopping List Python

Tags: python

I'm learning Python and I'm trying to make shopping List 
where you can add items

first it will ask you to add the items if the shopping list is empty 
it will be added automatically if not it will ask you where you would like 
to put the item (index)

but also I'm trying to make the program exit in certain condition like DONE
or HELP or SHOW but even that i put a condition for that but it's not working can anyone help me with this

hope I explained enough

```
import os 
shopping_list =[]

# Function for clearing the screen 
def clear_screen():
    os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")

def show_help():
    print("Enter 'Done' if you finish adding item \n Enter 'Show' to show your items \n Enter 'Help' toshow this help ")

# Function to show the items that you've entered to the list
def show_item():
    clear_screen()
    index = 1
    for item in shopping_list:
        print("{} {}.".format(index,item))
        index += 1

# Function to add items to the list    
def add_to_list():
    while True:
        new_item = input("Please enter the item that you would like to add to your shopping list ")
        if shopping_list and ((new_item.upper() != "DONE") or (new_item.upper() != "HELP") or (new_item.upper() != "SHOW")):
            position = input("Where you would like to add {} to the list \n press 'Enter' if you want to add to the end of the list".format(new_item))
            position = abs(int(position))
            shopping_list.insert(position - 1 , new_item)
            show_item()
        else:

            if new_item.upper() == "DONE":
                break    
            elif new_item.upper() == "SHOW":
                show_item()
                continue
            elif new_item.upper() == "HELP":
                show_help()
                continue
            else:
                shopping_list.append(new_item)
            show_item()

show_help()
add_to_list()
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. I think your logic statement is wrong, you need `and` instead of `or`. Right now all you need for the statement in the parentheses to be true, is that `new_item.upper()` is at least not one of those three words. It actually can't equate to False since two of the three are always true.

```
((new_item.upper() != "DONE") or (new_item.upper() != "HELP") or (new_item.upper() != "SHOW"))
```

If you have for example `done` the first statement is **False** ,but the other two are **True**, adding up to **True** in or-Statements.

```
>>> new_item = 'done'
>>> print((new_item.upper() != "DONE") or (new_item.upper() != "HELP") or (new_item.upper() != "SHOW"))
True
```

Comment: Thanks Man thats worked for me 
really appreciate it :)

Comment: Then you might wanna mark the answer as `accepted`, so it's clear that the question is closed, so to speak. Have fun!